# How to use map function for hooks useState properties

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to use map function for looping my list data in react-hooks useState but I stuck with an error that "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```
//1.Initial declaration
const App = props=>  {
const [state, changeState]= useState ({
    name:"",
    eventTitle:"",
    details:"",
    objdata:{},
    list:[],
    toggleIndex:"",
    editName: "",
    editEventTitle: "",
    editDetails: "",
    editObj: {}
});


//2.logic comes here


//3.tried using map


{(state.list.map((data,id)=>{
console.log ('loop data',data)
}))}
```

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the `state` variable above your `map` ?

Comment: As it is, your code should work. So, as @Treycos suspected maybe you are setting your state in a wrong way, so you lose `list` and got the error. Just share other parts of your component, please.

Comment: ok sure, but it will be a single whole component is that ok?

Comment: No problem with that. You can skip the irrelevant parts if you want of course. We just need to know where and how do you set your state.

Comment: I just cleared the error but still, I am not satisfied by the method. Why am I not able to execute the same code in hooks? Now I have to use the ternary operator to check its not empty. `{(state.list) ?
                <code>
              {(state.list.map((data,id)=>{.....}))}</code>:null} `

Comment: Again, you don't need to use this. Your code works fine as you can see in @adel's sandbox. There must be something else and unless we see your whole (or related parts) code we can't say anything.

Comment: @devserkan, please [code link ---->   https://justpaste.it/21a5l ] let me know my mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As we suspected you are not setting your state in the right way. I tried to explain in my comment, with hooks when you set your state it does not merge the updated properties with the current one. So, you should think about that. Right now you are setting your state like that:

```
const handleName = name => {
  changeState({
    name: name.target.value
  });
};
```

Here, you are setting the `name` property and lose other parts of your state. Hence, when you set your state, you lose `list` as well as other parts of your state. This is how you should do it:

```
const handleName = name => {
  const { target } = name;

  changeState(state => ({
    ...state,
    name: target.value,
  }));
};
```

You take the old state, keep the other properties by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it, then update the relevant part. I would use here `event` instead of `name`. It is not "name", it is "event" after all actually :)

```
const handleName = event => {
  const { target } = event;

  changeState(state => ({
    ...state,
    name: target.value,
  }));
};
```

Also, you have a few other problems and unnecessary parts in your code. For example, you are struggling too much to handle the submit and add an object to your `list`. You don't need an extra `objdata` in your state to push it to the `list`. If you want to construct an extra object, you can do it in the function itself.

Here is a very simple way to do it:

```
const submitHandle = () => {
  const { name, eventTitle, details } = state;
  const obj = { name, eventTitle, details };

  changeState(state => ({
    ...state,
    list: [ ...state.list, obj ],
  }))
};
```

Again, we are using spread operator to keep both the other parts of the state and while updating the `list`, to keep other objects. Do not set your state as you do in your `submitHandle` function. Try to think it simple :)

Also, you don't need to bind your functions when it is not necessary. You can find a working copy of the code below. I just removed unnecessary parts and fix the issues.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = props => {
  const [state, changeState] = useState({
    name: "",
    eventTitle: "",
    details: "",
    list: [],
    toggleIndex: "",
    editName: "",
    editEventTitle: "",
    editDetails: "",
    editObj: {}
  });

  const handleName = event => {
    const { target } = event;

    changeState(state => ({
      ...state,
      name: target.value
    }));
  };

  const handleEventTitle = event => {
    const { target } = event;

    changeState(state => ({
      ...state,
      eventTitle: target.value
    }));
  };

  const handleDetails = event => {
    const { target } = event;

    changeState(state => ({
      ...state,
      details: target.value
    }));
  };

  const submitHandle = () => {
    const { name, eventTitle, details } = state;
    const obj = { name, eventTitle, details };

    changeState(state => ({
      ...state,
      list: [...state.list, obj]
    }));
  };

  const resetHandle = () =>
    changeState(state => ({
      ...state,
      name: "",
      eventTitle: "",
      details: ""
    }));

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="display-5 text-center">Let's set your reminders</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bg-dark container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " />

          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
            <div className="card login-card ">
              <div className=" card-header ">
                <h3 className="text-center"> TO-DO LIST FORM</h3>
              </div>

              <div className="card-body">
                <form className="form-elements">
                  <input
                    value={state.name}
                    className="form-control form-inputs form-elements"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleName}
                    placeholder="user name"
                  />
                  <input
                    value={state.eventTitle}
                    className="form-control form-inputs form-elements"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleEventTitle}
                    placeholder="Event Title"
                  />
                  <input
                    value={state.details}
                    className="form-control form-inputs form-elements"
                    type="text"
                    onChange={handleDetails}
                    placeholder="Details "
                  />
                </form>
              </div>

              <div className="card-footer ">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={submitHandle}
                  className="btn-primary offset-lg-1 offset-md-0 btn-sm "
                >
                  Create
                </button>

                <button
                  type="reset"
                  onClick={resetHandle}
                  className="btn-primary offset-lg-5 offset-md-0 btn-sm"
                >
                  cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 " />
        </div>

        <div className="container-fluid bg-dark">
          <div className="row ">
            {state.list.map(data => (
              <div style={{ border: "1px black solid" }}>
                <p>{data.name}</p>
                <p>{data.eventTitle}</p>
                <p>{data.details}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        className="footer footer-copyright"
        style={{ background: "#e9ecef" }}
      >
        <div className="container">
          <h6 className=" text-center">Just make it work ;)</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your list is empty you will get this error just check if list is empty or not to solve the problem:

```
{if(state.list){
state.list.map((data,id)=>{
console.log ('loop data',data)
})
}}
```

Comment: Can't agree with you, because for `Array.map` empty array is completely valid. `Boolean([]) => TRUE`.

Comment: Yes, initially array has to be empty according to the logic. The code works fine using in a normal class component. As I am converting into React-Hooks I face this error. Help me to solve this.

Comment: @Little_Programmer check this codesandbox your code is working : https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-microservice-u7oqh

Comment: yes, I checked it but still, it reflects the error in my IDE.  :(