# How to use map function for hooks useState properties dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

My question is almost the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305227/how-to-use-map-function-for-hooks-usestate-properties).

In this case, the person has a map of states created in a hard coded way:

```
const App = props => {
  const [state, changeState] = useState({
    name: "",
    eventTitle: "",
    details: "",
    list: "",
    toggleIndex: "",
    editName: "",
    editEventTitle: "",
    editDetails: "",
  });
```

The difference is that I want to create those states dynamically, receiving them from another component. I tried something like this but it obviously did not work:

```
const App = props => {
  const [state, changeState] = useState({
    props.inputs.map((input, i) =>
      input = ""
    )
  });
```

Do you know any solution for this?

Comment: What does `props.inputs` look like?

Comment: @NicholasTower it has a list of input names that I want to have a state attached to them

Comment: `{
  "tag": "1231",
  "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "inputs": [
    "Field1",
    "Field2",
    "Field3",
    "Field4",
  ]
};`

Comment: You'd probably need to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `props.inputs` into a new object.

Comment: @EmileBergeron even with this new object, wouldn't I have to do the same thing then?

Comment: See [Christos'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60710833/1218980) answer, it's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `props.input` is just an array of the keys you want, you can populate the state object by iterating through the array and dynamically assigning the state object key with `[]`

```
const [state, changeState] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    props.input.forEach(item => changeState(prevState => ({...prevState, [item]: "" })));
}, [props.input])
```

Comment: This is not working for me, `{...prevState`  give me `declaration or statement expected` and `, [item]: "" });` gives me `',' expected`. How does this code works?

Comment: Sorry I missed the inner `()` (now added in the edit). Because you can access object keys by variables through the use of `[]` (ie. `obj[variable]`), you can leverage this to also assign them dynamically when you iterate through the array. The callback just lets you use the `...` spread syntax to include the rest of the keys that already exist in changeState but are not explicitly defined each time you modify it to add the next element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I still have `')' expected` in the end of `({...prevState, [item]: "" }));`, in the semicolon. And I understand the forEach part but what does this part do `, [props.input])`?

Comment: Oops I forgot to close the forEach (fixed). In this case I am triggering this to take place when the component mounts via useEffect (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), then specifying `[props.input]` as its second parameter to signify that it also occurs when props.input is updated by the parent component as well. I just assumed that this was an intended behavior but you can choose to modify it to however you like (ie. only once on mount and that's it).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `props.inputs` directly to the state combine it with `reduce` to create a new object from the `inputs` array:

```js
const App = props => {
  const [state, changeState] = useState(
    props.inputs.reduce((acc, cur, arr) => ({
      [cur]: "",
      ...acc
    }), {})
  );

  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.entries(state).map(([name, value], index) => (
        <li key={`li-${index}`}><strong>{name}</strong>: {`"${value}"`}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

#### If we use it like this:

```js
<App inputs={['name', 'details', 'list', 'editName']}/>
```

#### We'll have a result like this:

```
editName: ""
list: ""
details: ""
name: ""
```

You can check the working Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-component-dynamic-props?file=index.js).

Comment: Would appreciate to see the argument on why this is downvoted. `useState` has access to component props when it's initialized, so this will work for dynamic props passed when the component is created. We can of course use the `useEffect` hook if we have more dynamic props that need to be changed on renders.

Comment: I did not downvoted this as I appreciate any help. Despite this, I tried this suggestion and it just create a state with a list of the names on the inputs and not a map like structure that will hold the name and the value of the input fields

Comment: `props.inputs` is an array.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I misunderstood the question and didn't realize `props.inputs` is an array we need to use the elements for keys.

Comment: @PedroVieira you can do what you want using `reduce`. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was trying to get an item unique ID when click on mapped items, and opening a dialog to confirm selected item to be deleted, as shown below

```js
export const StatsTable = (props) => {
  const [itemUid, setItemUid] = useState('')
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true)
  }

  console.log('====================================')
  console.log(itemUid)
  console.log('====================================')
...
 return (
...
  {items.map((item) => {
...
    <Button
      type="submit"
      onClick={() =>
        handleClickOpen(setItemUid(item.uid))
      }
     >
       Delete
     </Button>
   }
}

...
```

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEEML.png)